# Question about the proof of this lemma: If $\alpha$, $\beta$ are ordinals, then either $\alpha \subset \beta$ or $\beta \subset \alpha.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Proof: Clearly $\alpha \cap \beta$ is an ordinal, $\alpha \cap \beta = \gamma.$ Then $\gamma = \alpha$ or $\gamma = \beta$. For, if not, then $\gamma \not= \alpha$ and $\gamma \not= \beta$. Then $\gamma \in \alpha$ and $\gamma \in \beta$ implying $\gamma \in \gamma$ which contradicts the definition of an ordinal (namely that set inclusion is a strict ordering of $\alpha$).

My question is that why does $\gamma \in \alpha$ and $\gamma \in \beta$ implies $\gamma \in \gamma$?

The lemma in question is #2.11 in Thomas Jech's Set Theory.

Comment: $\gamma\in\gamma$ contradicts one of the axioms of set theory, not the definition of ordinals!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I copied the proof almost word-to-word form the book. I think maybe you're not using the same definition for ordinals that I'm using. Ordinals are defined as $\alpha < \beta$ iff $\alpha \in \beta$, so the reasoning for the contradiction makes sense to me.

Comment: $\gamma\in\gamma$ contradicts the axiom of regularity quite directy, without involving ordinals (apply the axiom to the set $\{\gamma\}$.

Comment: We can work with ordinals even in set theories without the axiom of regularity. Hence using the definition of ordinals instead of regularity is fine (and in my eyes to be preferred)

Comment: Sure. But we are referring to a proof in a book which on page 1 postulates that axiom! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\gamma = \alpha \cap \beta$ by definition. Hence 
$$ \forall x \qquad x \in \gamma \iff x\in \alpha \land x \in \beta $$
Now apply this to $x = \gamma$.